# htaccess and php generated links

Tags: php

I have a form that a user fills out, which submits information to my mysql database.  On submission, my php code creates a url based on form data that was submitted and a unique ID.  Rather than having a new webpage populate my web directory based off of the generated url, I would like to point that url to something similar to a "profile" page.

So my php creates a link after a user has submitted the form that looks like this: http://localhost/State=ALCity=SeattleEvent=eventSubject=titleID=135

This link gets stored inside my table along with the data that was submitted by the user.  I've read that storing a url inside a table isn't practical, however for my purposes the table data will expire and get deleted within a certain amount of time.

In short, I'd like to be able to have a user click the link which will pull up data that was submitted.  Can I grab data from the url to pull that information up for the user?  Or will I need to change my setup that's already implemented? I can explain further if needed :)

Comment: Not clear what are you going to achieve? You want to give a user the link where here will get pre-filled form?

Comment: Basically I want to use that link to pull up information that was submitted via a web form.  I guess the closest example I can think of is Craigslist.  A user creates a listing, they get a unique link that takes them to their posting.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, this is a classic case for the mod_rewrite extension of Apache (since you mentioned .htaccess, I think you use Apache as webserver). With this mod, you can filter parts of the url and send it to your php script as normal `$_GET` parameters.

You will need something like this in your .htaccess (just out of my mind)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^State=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=SeattleEvent=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=titleID=([0-9]+)$ profile.php?state=$1&event=$2&id=$3
```

What this is actually doing, is that the Apache checks if the current requested url match the regular expression of this rule. If that is the case, it will call the profile.php and pass the "dynamic" part of the url as `$_GET` parameter (using the backreferences).

For further information, I recommence the [official mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), the [mod_rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) and [this nice tutorial](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls).

Comment: Yep, I am using Apache.  Could you further break down on what this does exactly?  To be honest, I'm not too familiar with what should be included in the .htaccess file.  I understand how the file functions within a web server, I just don't quite grasp how to utilize your above method.  And thank you for your help :)